# Why Red5 close after few seconds of inactivity?

Tags: java, process, red5, rtmp

I have a new Red5 server installed on my VPS, I'm running CentOS 5.7 X64 and Webmin are installed.
I have 768MB of Ram and two IP address.

Java 6, fulled compiled with 'ant prepare' and 'ant dist'.

When I'm running Red5 (with or without my homebrew webapps), the server close without special message after few seconds of inactivity. (5s to 2mins)

How can keep Red5 server online ?

See the full log;

```
Running on  Linux
Starting Red5
Red5 root: /usr/local/red5/dist
Configuation root: /usr/local/red5/dist/conf
Root: /usr/local/red5/dist
Deploy type: bootstrap
Logback selector: org.red5.logging.LoggingContextSelector
```

...

```
Setting default logging context: default
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.Launcher - Red5 Server 0.9.1 $Rev: 4059 $ (http://code.google.com/p/red5/)
Red5 Server 0.9.1 $Rev: 4059 $ (http://code.google.com/p/red5/)
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@7f70888e: startup date [Mon Oct 01 03:16:36 GMT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [red5.properties]
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@554d7745: defining beans [placeholderConfig,red5.common,red5.core,context.loader,pluginLauncher,tomcat.server]; root of factory hierarchy
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@4934ce4a: startup date [Mon Oct 01 03:16:37 GMT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [red5.properties]
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@54c01e99: defining beans [placeholderConfig,red5.server,jmxFactory,jmxAgent,serializer,deserializer,statusObjectService,rtmpCodecFactory,rtmptCodecFactory,remotingCodecFactory,streamableFileFactory,filePersistenceThread,sharedObjectService,streamService,providerService,consumerService,bandwidthFilter,schedulingService,warDeployService,remotingClient,object.cache,keyframe.cache,flv.impl,flvreader.impl,mp4reader.impl,mp3reader.impl,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean#1,streamExecutor,playlistSubscriberStream,clientBroadcastStream]; root of factory hierarchy
[WARN] [main] org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor - Invalid JavaBean property 'enableRmiAdapter' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableRmiAdapter(java.lang.String)]: [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableRmiAdapter(boolean)]
[WARN] [main] org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor - Invalid JavaBean property 'enableSsl' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableSsl(java.lang.String)]: [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableSsl(boolean)]
[WARN] [main] org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor - Invalid JavaBean property 'enableMinaMonitor' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableMinaMonitor(java.lang.String)]: [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableMinaMonitor(boolean)]
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.service.WarDeployer - War deployer service created
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@7b6ee3ec: startup date [Mon Oct 01 03:16:37 GMT 2012]; parent: ApplicationContext 'red5.common'
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [red5.properties]
[WARN] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer - Passing PropertyEditor instances into CustomEditorConfigurer is deprecated: use PropertyEditorRegistrars or PropertyEditor class names instead. Offending key [java.net.SocketAddress; offending editor instance: org.apache.mina.integration.beans.InetSocketAddressEditor@7d5dc37d
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@77a9f87c: defining beans [customEditorConfigurer,placeholderConfig,rtmpMinaConnManager,rtmpHandler,rtmpMinaIoHandler,rtmpTransport,rtmpMinaConnection,rtmptConnManager,rtmptHandler,rtmptServlet,rtmptConnection,rtmpsMinaIoHandler,rtmpsTransport]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@54c01e99
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - RTMP Mina Transport bound to /0.0.0.0:1935
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - RTMP Mina Transport Settings
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - Connection Threads: 4
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - I/O Threads: 16
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - TCP No Delay: true
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - Receive Buffer Size: 65536
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - Send Buffer Size: 271360
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - RTMP Mina Transport bound to /0.0.0.0:8443
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - RTMP Mina Transport Settings
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - Connection Threads: 4
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - I/O Threads: 16
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - TCP No Delay: true
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - Receive Buffer Size: 65536
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport - Send Buffer Size: 271360
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@673dd208: startup date [Mon Oct 01 03:16:37 GMT 2012]; parent: ApplicationContext 'red5.common'
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@32771eb1: defining beans [global.clientRegistry,global.serviceInvoker,global.mappingStrategy,global.context,global.handler,global.scope,red5.scopeResolver]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@54c01e99
[INFO] [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener - The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Setting connector: org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Address to bind: /0.0.0.0:5080
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Loading tomcat context
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Server root: /usr/local/red5/dist
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Config root: /usr/local/red5/dist/conf
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Application root: /usr/local/red5/dist/webapps
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Starting Tomcat servlet engine
[INFO] [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded - Starting tomcat server
[INFO] [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
[INFO] [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol - Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0.0.0.0-5080
[INFO] [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol - Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0.0.0.0-5080
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Dedicated RTMPT server configuration was not specified
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Dedicated RTMPS server configuration was not specified
Bootstrap complete
[INFO] [Launcher:/installer] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties]
[INFO] [Launcher:/vod] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties]
[INFO] [Launcher:/live] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties]
[INFO] [Launcher:/chatroulette] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties]
[INFO] [Launcher:/] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties]
[INFO] [Launcher:/vod] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@521c5cd7: defining beans [placeholderConfig,web.context,web.scope,web.handler]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@32771eb1
[INFO] [Launcher:/] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2d9f90e3: defining beans [placeholderConfig,web.context,web.scope]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@32771eb1
[INFO] [Launcher:/installer] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4453d3cf: defining beans [placeholderConfig,web.context,web.scope,web.handler,installer.service]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@32771eb1
[INFO] [Launcher:/chatroulette] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@495a2dc4: defining beans [placeholderConfig,web.context,web.scope,web.handler]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@32771eb1
[INFO] [Launcher:/live] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@bba92db: defining beans [placeholderConfig,web.context,web.scope,web.handler]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@32771eb1
[INFO] [Launcher:/chat] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties]
[INFO] [Launcher:/chat] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@677210a5: defining beans [placeholderConfig,web.context,web.scope,web.handler]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@32771eb1
[INFO] [Launcher:/installer] org.red5.server.service.Installer - Installer service created
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of stopping is the bad quality of the VPS. I have reinstalled the same stuff on another VPS and all running good.

Comment: That's the bad thing about some of these VPS providers, the "fine print". Another thing to watch out for is "shared bandwidth" between all server instances.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen at all.

You might start the server using the red5-highpref.sh, it will create a file called:
jvmstd.out in the logs directory that contains every System.out call or eventually Exceptions that are not shown in the log.

Comment: I can't use highpref, because my VPS is limited to 768MB and when I run it, Red5 use more than 800MB in memory...

Comment: Configure the values for Xms and Xmx in the script to lower values. Then you are able to use it.

Comment: I have exactly the same log of the first post, no change, no message wuth reason of closing.

Comment: I would also recommend you donwload and install the latest revision of Red5 instead of 0.9.1.

Comment: The latest version don't run with my webapps (major change in class)

Comment: I think you should fix the "major changes". There are only 2-3 changes necessary to fix an app to run in Red5 1.0 latest compared to 0.9.1.